# Is differencing or my code causing this pattern in my data?

Tags: r, time-series, distribution

Using Reddit data, I have formed time series across many people whose lags I wanted to examine more closely.

[image]

I have tried this with and without diff() data.
With the diff() data and this code I got this distribution of the lags and their means:

```
d_posts_ccf_mean_20_50_test_test <- d_posts_ccf_dfc_20_50_test_test %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mean = mean(abs(c_across(acf1:acf177)))) %>%  mutate(sd = sd(abs(c_across(acf1:acf177))))
```

[image]

In this code-snippet I used abs() because I thought it was necessary to work with abs() so that the negative and positive coefficients do not cancel each other out...But then it seemed wrong to me.

```
d_posts_ccf_mean_20_50_test_test_ohne_abs <- d_posts_ccf_dfc_20_50_test_test %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mean = mean((c_across(acf1:acf177)))) %>%  mutate(sd = sd((c_across(acf1:acf177))))
```

[image]

Which is why then made it without the abs() and I got this plot. I thought the upper distribution would have made more sense because the time series around zero correlate more strongly with each other because they are simply closer together in time. All in all, however, the coefficients are extremely small and almost zero, which is why I was also satisfied with the other distribution. I changed the code a bit to make sure, that the pattern is stable:

```
lag_con_means <- colMeans(d_posts_ccf_dfc_20_50_t, na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

And same pattern.

Next I worked with the undifferenced data, and now there is the first pattern again. So the undifferenced data and the abs() function had a similar impact, so that all coefficients are in a positive area. Still I am left with confusion, why the funnel-shape disappears sometimes. I was hoping that somebody would know how this can happen. I can imagine its difficult to evaluate without seeing all of the data/ steps but I am also grateful for hints that I could check again on my data!

```
lag_con_no_diff_means <- colMeans(d_posts_20_50_no_diff_acf_t, na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]